Is this true? $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^n\vee\mathbb{R}P^n)\cong\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^n)*\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^n)$
I'm not even sure where to start with this. Van Kampen seems like an obvious solution, but the lack of visual intuition is really messing me up. If anybody can try to explain this to me, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!
For additional context: I'm currently practicing dealing with not-so-concrete topological spaces when it comes to Cartesian and wedge products. This is for the sake of becoming better equipped in dealing with homology and fundamental groups questions.

You do not need visual intuition to solve this problem.

Yes, Van Kampen applies in general for wedge sums of nice enough spaces (e.g. CW complexes), where the summands are deformation retracts of open subsets (and the intersection is contractible). See Hatcher example 1.21

You can visualize $\mathbb{R}P^n$ as $S^n$ with antipodal points identified or the upper half $n$-sphere with opposite boundary points identified (the boundary being the equator). This can help you visualize the wedge product. And I agree with Moishe's comment that you do not need visual intuition to solve this problem.

this is a tough one though! for example the $\pi_2$ is the same is not finitely generated :(

@AndresMejia Beg your pardon? The first higher nontrivial homotopy group of $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n \vee \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ is $\pi_n$, which is in fact not finitely generated. I fail to see how this is relevant to a question asking about the fundamental group, however.

saw rp^2. the comment was in in view of visual intuition

pardon granted however lol

To prevent this from going unanswered:
Van Kampen is the obvious solution, and you don't need to resort to visual intuition at all: All you need to note is that the wedge point $x_0$ has a contractible neighborhood $U$ such that each of the two summands $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n_i$ ($i = 1, 2$) of $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n_1 \vee \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n_2$ is a deformation retract of $U \cup \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n_i$; for this you can either exploit the fact that CW-complexes are locally contractible (Proposition A.4 in Hatcher) or that $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^n$ is a manifold.

yep, this is the exact response I was looking for. That does it. Thanks again Ben!
